# IE9 compatibility mode issue for calling cross domain API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ie-compatibility-mode

We are working in angular(version 1.6) application, where our application is calling other application API built in Node.js which is running on the user machine. This Node.js application is running on https (with valid certificate) on user local machine.
This API call from Angular application to Node.js application is working fine on Chrome/Firefox and IE10/IE11 but not working with IE9 compatibility mode. The line of API call execution is happening in IE9 compatibility mode but the network tab is not capturing the API logs and there is no error in console as well. 
Looking for some help here.

Comment: Could it be that IE9 doesn't know about the certificate?

Comment: It works If I directly hit the API in the browser in IE9 compatibility mode.

Comment: Can you use the debugger to step though the code? Or add a lot of console.log statements to see what it is running? Maybe you get an error inside a promise, and that is not taken care of.

Comment: Can you share the related code about how to call the API from the Angular application? And can you use F12 network tab to check the api request status?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT   return providers.$http.get(`${nodeDomain}/test/status`, {
            params: {},
        }).then(storeUserInSession)
        .catch(requestFailedFromTerminal);                                                                                Request status is not being captured in network logs, but the same is working in IE10/11